# Python 3 course, having issue with extra space before period in the end of the print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm taking a python intro course so this stuff is still fairly basic, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried multiple things, I know that the comma in a print statement automatically adds a space, but I can't add a plus and the period without getting an error

here is my code:

```
bonus = survey_completers / class_size

avg = my_current_average + bonus

rounded_bonus = round(bonus, 1)

rounded_avg = round(avg, 1)

textOne = str("After the")

textTwo = str("point bonus, my average is")

textThree = str(".")

print(textOne, rounded_bonus, textTwo, rounded_avg, textThree)
```

giving the output:

```
After the 0.5 point bonus, my average is 87.6 .
```

When expected output is that sentence with the period right behind the 87.6

---

I've tried things such as:

```
bonus = survey_completers / class_size

avg = my_current_average + bonus

rounded_bonus = round(bonus, 1)

rounded_avg = round(avg, 1)

textOne = str("After the")

textTwo = str("point bonus, my average is")

print(textOne, rounded_bonus, textTwo, rounded_avg + ".")
```

which gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "CIOSBonus.py", line 40, in <module>
print(textOne, rounded_bonus, textTwo, rounded_avg + ".")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Command exited with non-zero status 1

Comment: Any reason to not use an f-string, eg: `print(f'{textOne} {rounded_bonus} {textTwo} {rounded_avg}{textThree}')` ?

Comment: Check out [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) it's pretty great; `print("prefix {} middle {}.".format("a", "b"))`

Comment: @JonClements We haven't gone over f-strings yet, but problem is now solved. Thank you all so much!

Comment: Hi Jake84 on SO we don't add Solved to the title, please check the green check mark of the answer that solved your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the float to a string:

```py
print(textOne, rounded_bonus, textTwo, str(rounded_avg) + ".")
```

You can also set `sep=""`, default is `sep=" "`

```py
print(textOne, " ", rounded_bonus, " ", textTwo, " ", rounded_avg, ".", sep="")
```

Another option is to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```py
print(f"{textOne} {rounded_bonus} {textTwo} {rounded_avg}.")
```

You can also use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```py
print("%s %f %s %f." %(textOne, rounded_bonus, textTwo, rounded_avg))
```

```
%s is string
%i is int
%f is float
```

I think that using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) is the best and cleanest way.

Also, when creating a string you don't have to have `str("")`.

For example:

```py
x = "Test String"
```

Comment: I ended up doing the first line with converting the float to a string, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
bonus = survey_completers / class_size

avg = my_current_average + bonus

rounded_bonus = round(bonus, 1)

rounded_avg = round(avg, 1)

result = f"After the {rounded_bonus} point bonus, my average is {rounded_avg}."

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### FIX

You don't have to do `str("  ")`, a surrounded quote value is already a string, but to join a number and a string, you first need to convert both of them to string

```
textOne = "After the"
textTwo = "point bonus, my average is"
print(textOne, rounded_bonus, textTwo, str(rounded_avg) + ".")
```

---

#### Improve

The better is still to use string formatting, here with `f-string`, you can even handle the `round` part in the format

```
bonus = 0.510101010
avg = 87.612121
print(f"After the {bonus:0.1f} point bonus, my average is {avg:0.1f}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print('After the {} point bonus, my average is {}.'.format(rounded_bonus, rounded_avg))
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, F strings were introduced to make this bit of code a lot easier. See below:

```
rounded_bonus = 0.5

rounded_avg = 87.6

print(f'After the {rounded_bonus} point bonus, my average is {rounded_avg}.')
```

Here is a link to learn more: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

`print` with multiple arguments always shows a space between the arguments, i.e. before `textThree` in your example. If you replace the final `print` function with one of these you won't get the spaces:

```
print(textOne + str(rounded_bonus) + textTwo + str(rounded_avg) + textThree)
```

or

```
print("After the {} points bonus, my average is {}.".format(rounded_bonus, rounded_avg))
```

or

```
print(f"After the {rounded_bonus} points bonus, my average is {rounded_avg}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to add a string to a float. That's not possible! Its like adding "a" + 2. Makes no sense, right? So, as the other answers have pointed out, you transform the float into a string:

```
str(rounded_avg)
```

That way python can add the "." to it. It's quite interesting that python can know how to "add" things together based on what those things are, you can read more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator).

Also, its not necessary to wrap a string around `str()`, as it is already a string. Remember, "strings are always surrounded by quotes".

So, knowing all that, your code would look like this:

```
bonus = survey_completers / class_size
avg = my_current_average + bonus
rounded_bonus = round(bonus, 1)
rounded_avg = round(avg, 1)
textOne = "After the"
textTwo = "point bonus, my average is"
print(textOne, str(rounded_bonus), textTwo, str(rounded_avg) + ".")
```

Even better, you could use [formatted strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
print(f"After the {rounded_bonus} point bonus, my average is {rounded_avg}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

> the comma in a print statement automatically adds a space

Yeah, that's for convenience. When you type

```
print(x, y, z)
```

because you want to know what's in those variables, having an automatic space is easier than having to type this abomination:

```
print(x, " ", y, " ", z)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Yes, in python, you can't add a string and a float. You can convert the float to string:

```
print(textOne, rounded_bonus, textTwo, str(rounded_avg) + ".")
```

But you should really be doing:

```
print("After the %.1f point bonus, my average is %.1f." % (bonus, avg))
```

%.1f means a float rounded with 1 digit after the decimal point, so you can get rid of the line with round(). This is the standard printf() format, if you like archeology it comes from BCPL back in 1966, which explains why it looks weird. There is a more modern version in python3, see azro's answer.

```
textOne = str("After the")
```

Also you don't need to convert a string into a string. It's already a string.